# assign codes to pandas dataframe using apply without iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I want to code a dataframe of numbers according to the sequence of the number within a given row.  The sequence of numbers itself has meaning that I want to capture.  I was able to solve this using a loop, but it's extremely time consuming.

Starting df:

```
   2017-10-06  2017-10-07  2017-10-08
id                                                                 
1         1.0        46.0         5.0   
2        16.0         1.0         0.0   
3        23.0       123.0         0.0   
4         1.0         0.0         0.0   
5         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

I've created a function that I pass each column.  It needs knowledge of the previous column, and assigns a coding string.

The coded df looks like:

```
   2017-10-06  2017-10-07  2017-10-08
id                                                                 
1      active      active      active   
2      active      active  inactive_1   
3      active      active  inactive_1   
4      active  inactive_1  inactive_1   
5  inactive_1  inactive_1  inactive_3
```

I currently am able to iterate through each column once, assigning 'active' (easy to look for a nonzero value), and then assign a count of zeros (if a zero is found, look at the previous value and add 1 unless the last value is 'active', in which case start at 1)

```
for i in range(1, len(cols)):
    test = cols[i]
    prev = cols[i-1]
    df[cols[i]] = df.apply(lambda row: assign_active(row[prev], row[test]), axis=1)
```

That intermediate df looks like:

```
   2017-10-06  2017-10-07  2017-10-08
id                                                                 
1      active      active      active   
2      active      active           1   
3      active      active           1   
4      active           1           2   
5           1           2           3
```

I then iterate again, and anything that isn't 'active' gets coded appropriately using the same method of iterating through each column and using apply with my function.  That function looks at the specific value and assigns the right code (you'll notice there isn't an 'active_2', so its not just manipulating strings)

I would like to figure out a way to do this without iterating through each column at all, let alone twice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, define a function that uses `np.where` (note, this is extremely fast).

```
def foo(s):
     return np.where(s > 0, 'active', 'inactive_' + (s.eq(0).cumsum()).astype(str))
```

Now, call `df.apply` along the first axis.

```
df = df.apply(foo, 1)
print(df)
    2017-10-06  2017-10-07  2017-10-08
id                                    
1       active      active      active
2       active      active  inactive_1
3       active      active  inactive_1
4       active  inactive_1  inactive_2
5   inactive_1  inactive_2  inactive_3
```

This is probably what you want, given your intermediate output.

Comment: coldspeed - this solves the problem as I described it - thanks!  My problem has changed, so I need the cumsum to reset after another value is seen.  for instance, if the value in [5, '2017-10-07'] was 1 in the starting df, then the bottom row in the output df would need to be [inactive_1, active, inactive_1]